# Are Web services with SAML still stateless?

Tags: web-services, security, state, soa, saml

As far as I understand web services are stateless. However, if I use SAML to authorise the service consumer before passing the request to the service provider, is the web service still stateless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how you perform the authentication / authorization step with SAML. A stateful service is one where subsequent requests to the service depend on the results of the first request. A typical service reads the SAML assertion, extracts the subject and claims then uses them for authentication or authorization right there in the same execution context. This is still stateless. BUT if the outcome of that step is something that tracks the client (i.e. a cookie or another type of state/affinity mechanism), then your service is stateful.

It isn't so much the authentication protocol (SAML) or the representation of the token (also SAML), it's what your service does with it.